# How to write JavaScript for iframe and not iframe (same content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

**Setup**

I will be accessing content on my page sometimes from an iframe and sometimes from the same content not in an iframe.

**Problem**

I'm trying to figure out a way to write javascript once and include both ways of accessing that content during the declaration of the var...

so far example

```
var $Holder;

if($('#MyHolder iframe').contents().length > 0) { 
    $Holder = $('#MyHolder iframe');
}
else {
    $Holder = $('#MyHolder');
}
```

but I can't do this since if the content is in an iframe I need to access it this way:

```
$Holder.contents().find('#SomeButton').on('click',function(){});
```

and this doesn't work if the content is directly on the page. This also does not work if I add .contents().

Comment: I'm not able to set $Holder to $("#MyHolder iframe").contents(); This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be able to set your $Holder to the contents() of the iframe like so:

```
var $Holder;

if($('#MyHolder iframe').contents().length > 0) { 
    $Holder = $('#MyHolder iframe').contents();
}
else {
    $Holder = $('#MyHolder');
}
```

Then you should be able to access elements in either case like so:

```
$Holder.find('#SomeButton').on('click',function(){});
```

Comment: It's a strange setup. When trying this, I can't register an $.on('click',function(){}); the same way, because when the content is in an iframe I need to use $.find('#something').on('click',function(){}); and when not in an iframe $('#something').on('click',function(){}); when not in an iframe. Maybe if I setup to use Find everywhere and do as you suggested, it will work as I want. I'll try this thanks.

Comment: This answer will work if your content in the inframe and document are both done rendering and then you try setting the .contents(), which makes sense, Thanks.

Comment: Ah true, if there is an iframe, you'd have to wait for it to load before you could talk to its contents. I'm assuming you've already figured that you can use the load event for that.

Comment: First attempt was to add a TimeOut of 100ms which made me realize it was the iframe loading after the page content was done. and found the load from google, Thanks for your help!